# WPF - Why does my UserControl stop working?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, code-behind

WPF - Why does my `UserControl` stop working when I uncomment commented line?
When i commented my control it added rows on start when i uncomment it not added any rows by `LoadRow()` and even on trying to add on runtime by some `textbox` and `button` functionality?

From code-behind of custom UserControl:

```
    public void LoadRows()
    {
        Rows.Add(new Row("221 331,44", GetOutputFromInput));
        Rows.Add(new Row("2 331,44", GetOutputFromInput));
        Rows.Add(new Row("331,44", GetOutputFromInput));
        Rows.Add(new Row("0,44", GetOutputFromInput));
        Rows.Add(new Row { Input = "333", Output = "555"});
        Rows.Add(new Row { Input = "333", Output = "555"});
    }

    //public DependencyProperty RowsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Rows", typeof(ObservableCollection<Row>), typeof(TriggerListAdd));
    public ObservableCollection<Row> Rows
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get a dependency property just by uncommenting that line. You also have to write a correct CLR property wrapper:

```
public DependencyProperty RowsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(Rows),
    typeof(ObservableCollection<Row>),
    typeof(TriggerListAdd));

public ObservableCollection<Row> Rows
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<Row>)GetValue(RowsProperty);
    set { SetValue(RowsProperty, value);
}
```

I would also recommend to change the type of the property to `IEnumerable` to achieve more flexibility when using your control.